# What's best way to take input of more than 1 list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I need to put user input in list like:

```
11 20
22 30
32 45
34 54
.. ..
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(n):
    c, d = map(int, input().split())
    a.append(c)
    b.append(d)
```

Is there any better way than this?

Comment: Do you need the input format to be exactly the way you specified? What is wrong with this way of doing it?

Comment: You can append directly via `[map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(n)]` but that's about it. I'd advise strongly against, tho, because every entry that doesn't consist of a list of integers separated by whitespace would break it. Some basic `input()` validation is always a good idea.

Comment: As long as you catch ValueError and remind the user of the format you expect the input in, this is actually a decent way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you like your solution?

Comment: @wwii I thought it as lengthier solution.

Comment: @AnkS - what makes yours a 'lengthier solution'? Because the answer you picked is computationally significantly lengthier solution. I'd even call your solution not 'lengthy' enough as it lacks any validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
ins = [input("Two integers separated by a whitespace: ") for _ in range(n)]
a, b = [int(i.split()[0]) for i in ins], [int(i.split()[1]) for i in ins]
```

Consider the exception, I think that code as below is better:

```
tip = "Enter two integers separated by a whitespace: "    
while n > 0:
    try:
        c, d = map(int, input(tip).split())
        n -= 1
        a.append(c)
        b.append(d)
    except:
        print('invalid input!\n')
```

Comment: The first one is incredibly wasteful - two splits over the same data to pick both sides - you can do it with a single split and unzip if you want an one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Just needs some user prompt and validation.  Simply catching ValueError would do it...

```
for i in range(n):
    while True:
        try:
            c, d = map(int, input("enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace").split())
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Try again...\n")
    a.append(c)
    b.append(d)
```

Results in interpreter:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> for i in range(n):
        while True:
            try:
                c, d = map(int, input("enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: ").split())
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Try again...\n")
        a.append(c)
        b.append(d)
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 1 2
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 5
Try again...

enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 5 6
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 10 11
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 3112 3232
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 1111
Try again...

enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 323 333
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 324 334
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 1 1
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 2 2
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 3 3
enter 2 numbers separated by whitespace: 4 4
>>> a
[1, 5, 10, 3112, 323, 324, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[2, 6, 11, 3232, 333, 334, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```